# Golang concurrency deadlocks as soon as I add a channel for response

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I got a function that is supposed to retrieve information in a goroutine and send it back to the channel as it finishes.

```
func getTopLikeSupporter(username string, session Session, session1 Session) ([]models.Supporter, *string, error) {
    var supporters = make(map[string]models.Supporter)

    posts, err := getThreads(username, 2, session)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    chLikes := make(chan []models.ThreadPostLikeUser)

    wg.Add(1)
    massReceiveThreadPostLikes(username, session, posts, &wg, chLikes)


    wg.Wait()
    close(chLikes)

    fmt.Println("finished receiving likes")
}
```

```
func massReceiveThreadPostLikes(username string, session Session, threadPosts []models.ThreadPosts, waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- []models.ThreadPostLikeUser) {
    var threadPostLikeUser []models.ThreadPostLikeUser

    defer waitGroup.Done()
    for _, post := range threadPosts {
        for _, post := range post.Data.MediaData.Edges {
            threadCode := post.Node.ThreadItems[0].Post.Code
            postID := post.Node.ID
            username := post.Node.ThreadItems[0].Post.User.Username

            fmt.Println("Getting likes for post: " + threadCode)

            postLikeUsers, err := getThreadPostLikes(postID, username, threadCode, session)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            threadPostLikeUser = append(threadPostLikeUser, postLikeUsers)

            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second / 2)
        }
    }

    ch <- threadPostLikeUser
}
```

As soon as I add the channel repsonse, the program just deadlocks and the wait group never finishes.

If I delete the reponse to the channel everything works fine, but I dont get why that is the case.

Comment: you have nothing receiving from `ch`, so it's blocked. See some basic concurrency examples in [A Tour of Go: Channels](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2)

Comment: @JimB damn u are right, storing the channel response unblocked the goroutine. Thanks for your help !